# Get right part of string in Android app

Tags: java, android, substring

Ok, I am trying to get the right three characters of a string in an Android app I'm writing.

Based on the research I've done in the SDK and online I should be able to use something like the following to do it.

```
millisecondsD = millisecondsD.substring(millisecondsD.length() -3, millisecondsD.length());
```

However, I get a force close whenever I try to use to use the code above.  Am I just missing something super simple?

Comment: use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close". Your string may be `null` or shorter than three characters, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to check to see that the string is at least 3 characters long and not `null` first.

```
if (millesecondsD != null && millisecondsD.length() >=3)
    millesecondsD = milisecondsD.substring(milisecondsD.length() - 3);
```

Also, you can leave off the second parameter if you want.

Example:

```
String:
I'm a chunky monkey from funky town
01234567890123456789012345678901234
         10        20        30
```

So, in this case the last 3 chars are 34, 33, and 32.  The indices you have in your code are correct.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  Was because for the first 100ms it isn't 3 characters long.

Comment: @smccloud, glad to help.  Make sure you click the green check mark to show that this answer is the one that solved your problem.